# A two dimensional matrix of lists in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I define two dimensional matrix (fixed size) of lists (dynamic in size).

If not, what would be the best way to something that would achieve same effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
nY=5;nX=5;
A=cell(nY,nX);
```

Then you can add elements as you like:

```
A{3,4}(15)=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use Matlab's [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) rather than matrices.  Post again if you need more and more specific assistance.

Comment: Great, thanks! Another question, if I have a cell array `A = cell(5,5);`, how do I add an element to say `A(2,2)`?